# How to show the maximal interval for $\dot{x}(t)=-cx^2(t)+\frac{x^2(t)}{1+x^2(t)}$ is $[0,\infty)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

The following differential equation has the maximal interval as $[0,\infty)$:

$$
\dot{x}(t)=-cx^2(t)+\frac{x^2(t)}{1+x^2(t)}
$$

where $c>0$.

My try:
We need to show the solution lives in a bounded set, then we are done. Since $\frac{x^2(t)}{1+x^2(t)} \leq 1$ we can write

$$
\dot{x}(t)\leq-cx^2(t)+1
$$

I do not know how to find the upper bound for $x(t)$ and how to come up with a lower bound for $x(t)$.

Comment: Is there some condition like $x(0)>0$? If the initial value is negative and large enough, then the slope is negative and the dynamic essentially $\dot x=-cx^2$, which has a pole at some finite time. Are there any conditions on $c$, like $c>1$?

Comment: @LutzL: Sorry $c>0$ but no condition on initial condition.

Comment: if $x^2(t)$ gets too big, then $\dot x$

Comment: Can you check again that the first exponent is correct? The claim would be correct for an odd integer power, $-cx$ or $-cx^3$.

Answer (score 2):

As with any one-dimensional autonomous dynamical system with differentiable right side, it is sufficient to consider the roots and signs between roots of the right side function. The roots are at $x_0=0$ and $c(1+x^2)=1\iff x_\pm=\pm\sqrt{\frac1c-1}$ which are only real for $c\in(0,1]$.

As $x=0$ is a constant solution, any other solution has an invariant sign.

For $c>1$, the right side is negative everywhere for $x\ne 0$, so that all solutions are falling. This means that positive solutions are bounded and thus defined on all of $[0,\infty)$. Negative solutions are unbounded and will reach a point where the quadratic term is dominant over the second bounded term. From that point on there will be a blow-up to $-\infty$.

For $c\le 1$ the global image is the same, only that there will be a strip of bounded solutions between the stationary  solutions $x=x_\pm$.