# How to show the solution for $\dot{x}(t)=-cx^2(t)+\frac{x^2(t)}{1+x^2(t)}$ is bounded?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to show the following differential equation has a bounded solution.:

$$
\dot{x}(t)=-cx^2(t)+\frac{x^2(t)}{1+x^2(t)}
$$

where $c>0$.

My try:
Since $\frac{x^2(t)}{1+x^2(t)} \leq 1$ we can write

$$
\dot{x}(t)\leq-cx^2(t)+1
$$

I do not know how to find the upper bound for $x(t)$ and how to come up with a lower bound for $x(t)$.

Comment: you asked the same thing yesterday....

Comment: Hi, the same question was asked yesterday so I am voting for closure as duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

If you assume at first that x(t) is unbounded as $t \to \infty$, the last term drops out. This leaves us with  $\dot{x}(t) = -cx(t)+1$. Using again that we assume x(t) to be unbounded, the term 1 can be disregarded, so we are in asymptotic approximation left with: $$\dot{x}(t) = -cx(t)^2$$

This has the following solution:

$$x(t) = \frac{1}{c}\left(\frac{1}{t+K_{1}}\right)$$

Clearly, this solution is bounded as $t \to \infty$, so therefore, we are in contradiction with our assumption.

The only problem we run into is that we require some initial condition on $x$. If we assume this initial condition to be bounded, then I think we are fine.

edit: Corrected $\dot{x}(t) = -cx(t)$ into $\dot{x}(t) = -cx(t)^2$

Comment: the power of $-cx^(t)$ is 2 not one!

Comment: $\dot x=-cx$ has the solution $x_0e^{-ct}$, $\dot x=-cx^2$ has the solution $\frac{x_0}{1+cx_0t}$, both are different from your formula.

Comment: Sorry I made an error, I should have written $\dot{x}(t) = -cx(t)^2$.

Comment: All errors should be gone now

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Your answer gives only some heuristics, and is not on a par with rigorous mathematical reasoning, I'm afraid.  For an answer satisfying the standard requirements in mathematics, see [How to show the maximal interval for $\dot{x}(t)=−c x^2(t) + \frac{x^2(t)}{1+x^2(t)}$ is $[0,\infty)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3165447/how-to-show-the-maximal-interval-for-dotxt-cx2t-fracx2t1x2t), as noted by Rebellos.